# How to find the shortest path not containing a pattern?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, pattern-matching, shortest-path

I am using Neo4j 5.9.0 community

**Problem description** :
My graph only has one type of relationship [:Relationship], and one type of node (:Node).
I want to find the shortest path between two nodes, but I do not want the shortest path returned to contain this pattern : **(:Node)<-[:Relationship]-(:Node)-[:Relationship]->(:Node)**

I have read [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/patterns/concepts/) that

> If the MATCH clause of the shortestPath function includes a WHERE clause, a shortest path that satisfies the WHERE clause conditions is returned if one exists.

so this should be possible, and I have tested without using the shortestPath function that paths that verify this requirement indeed exist in my graph.

**What I have tried:**
I have tested mutliple ways to filter the shortest path returned, but none of them were successful.
I tried using the **exists{}** subquery:

```
match p = shortestPath((startNode:Node {id : 1})-[:Relationship*]-(endNode:Node {id : 2})) 
where none(pathNode in nodes(p) where exists{
match (n1:Node)<-[:Relationship]-(pathNode)-[:Relationship]->(n2:Node)
where ((n1 in nodes(p)) and (n2 in nodes(p)))
}) 
return p
```

which returns 'Unknown expression type during transformation (class org.neo4j.cypher.internal.ir.ast.ExistsIRExpression)',

as well as using **isEmpty()** predicate function :

```
match p = shortestPath((startNode:Node {id : 1})-[:Relationship*]-(endNode:Node {id : 2}))
where isEmpty ([(n1)<-[:Relationship]-(n2)-[:Relationship]->(n3) where ((n1 in nodes(p)) and (n2 in nodes(p)) and (n3 in nodes(p))) | n2.id])
return p
```

which returns 'Unknown expression type during transformation (class org.neo4j.cypher.internal.ir.ast.ListIRExpression)'

I do not understand why the queries above do not work properly. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After explaining [the problem on the Neo4j GitHub](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/13286), the Neo4j team addressed this bug and declared that it has been **fixed in the 5.15 release.** I have not personally verified nor tested this.

Answer (score 0):

There was [a somewhat related issue with the EXISTS subquery](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/13098) in version 5.6 that was supposed to be fixed in Neo4j 5.11. And indeed, I tested the sample query provided by that issue in 5.11 and it did not generate any error. But that query did not involve the `shortestPath` function.

However, your 2 queries, which seem reasonable to me, continue to cause the same errors in 5.11. The issue seem related to processing of the `shortestPath` function. If you replaced the first clause of each query with `MATCH (startNode:Node {id : 1})-[:Relationship*]-(endNode:Node {id : 2})`, the errors go away.

You should create a [new issue](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/new/choose) for the `shortestPath` function, and use your 2 queries (or something simpler) as examples.